# NGINX + Wordpress Config: Install Wordpress under subfolder but with a separate root?

Tags: nginx, php, configuration, wordpress

I have a problem which I came close to solving but last step failed me.

I have a WP install at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) on Ubuntu/Nginx I have no issues there, I also wanted to have another installation for our German site with /de such as ([www.example.com/de](http://www.example.com/de)) structure but, I wanted to keep the wordpress source files under a separate folder for the German site, not place them in a subfolder of the main site, so the root locations would be:

Root for main site ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) -> var/www/example.com
Root for German site ([www.example.com/de](http://www.example.com/de)) -> var/www/example.com-de

I have setup my config file as following, I can access to homepage on the German site and no permalinks enabled, everything works finr but when I activate the pretty links, it takes me back to actual domain "www.example.com"

I followed this tutorial and everything worked until the last step:

https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /de {
    alias /var/www/example.com.de;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }
    }


    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
}
```

Can anybody point out what I am missing on the config file and if this is the most optimla way to set it up what I want to achieve?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the root URL in your DE WordPress installation?

Comment: I really ask me of the vendor support site is such bad to use the KB of them, I found [this](https://wordpress.com/support/set-up-a-multilingual-blog) and it shows multiple options

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I just made some edits to further clarify the question, much appreciate the support. Thanks.